# Skin Adhesive Emulsion

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I'm working on upgrading my current skin adhesive emulsion. It is a roll-on skin adhesive used to keep clothing attached to the skin. Ingredients are; Alcohol Denae,Ethyl Ester of PM/MA Copolymer,Water, Butylene Glycol, and Aminomethyl Proponal.

What ingredient(s) could be used to:

- Improve formula so that it is more pliable(as far as the skin moving with fabric).
- Still maintain a strong bond/hold(possibly even stronger then current formula).
- Have the overall formula be slightly less wet/runny (as it sometimes absorbs through clothing).
- And when the formula sets, remains fairly matte/dry to the touch.